# lazy attribute in Swift equivalent to lazy Init getter in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, lazy-evaluation

Is the lazy attribute in Swift equivalent to overriding the getter with a lazy loading pattern in Objective C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy attribute before its declaration.

So, mostly, yes.

> You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var keyword), because its initial value may not be retrieved until after instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be declared as lazy.”

Remember that on Swift you have the option to declare custom getters and setters for your properties:

```
var name : String?{
  get{
    return "Oscar"
  }
  set(newValue){

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would there be any benefits declaring a lazy pattern in the custom getter in Swift (if possible) over using the @Lazy attribute?

Comment: None that I have seen on this 24 hours of testing. That will probably change, though.

Comment: My pleasure. You can always select the answer as correct :-)

Answer (score 3):

Referring to this:

```
lazy var x = SomeFunction()
```

The closest equivalent in Objective-C would be something like:

```
@property BOOL xHasBeenSet;
@property id x;

- (id)x
{
    if (!self.xHasBeenSet) {
        self.x = SomeFunction();
    }
    return x;
}

- (void)setX:(id)x
{
    _x = x;
    self.xHasBeenSet = YES;
}
```

Here you would only see `SomeFunction` called the first time you read `x`, but only if you don't set `x` first.  It's important to note that there is only one code path where the right side gets called and it never resets back to `xHasBeenSet = NO`.

Comment: ??? that would be .... weird. two properties to make one lazy? just do `- (id)x { if(!_x) _x = someFunction()`

Comment: @Daij-Djan For cases where `SomeFunction()` could return 0 or `nil`, the RHS would still only be called once.

Comment: ok -- then use a dispatch_once `- (id)x { dispatch_once(^{ if(!_x) _x = boa; }); return _x; }` [I left out the token because I always get the syntax wrong anyways :D]

Comment: `self.x = ...` was out of laziness since setting flipped two variables.

Comment: @Daij-Djan That misses the case where someone sets `x = 0` before calling. It's tricky business.  But yes, there's probably also a lock involved for thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

mainly yes-- it can't be a computed property though