# Lazy property initialization in Swift

Tags: swift

How would you implement the following pattern in Swift?

The `Container` class is initialized with a JSON array that contains dictionaries. These dictionaries are used to initialize `Entry` classes. However, the initialization of the `Entry` objects happens lazily, when either the `entries` or the `searchEntries` property is accessed.

```
@interface Container

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSArray *entryDicts;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSArray* entries;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSDictionary *searchEntries;

@end



@implementation Container

- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _entryDicts = array;
    }
    return self;
}

@synthesize entries = _entries;
- (NSArray *)entries
{
    [self loadEntriesIfNeeded];
    return _entries;
}

@synthesize entriesByNumber = _entriesByNumber;
- (NSDictionary *)entriesByNumber
{
    [self loadEntriesIfNeeded];
    return _entriesByNumber;
}

- (void)loadEntriesIfNeeded
{
    if (_entries == nil) {
        // Load entries
        NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.entriesDict count]];
        NSMutableDictionary *entriesByNumber = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[self.entriesDict count]];

        [self.entriesDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *number, NSDictionary *entryDict, BOOL *stop) {
            Entry *entry = [[Entry alloc] initWithDictionary:entryDict container:self];
            [entries addObject:entry];
            entriesByNumber[number] = entry;
        }];

        _entries = [entries copy];
        _entriesByNumber = [entriesByNumber copy];

        // Delete dictionaries
        _entriesDict = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that this question has largely been answered, but to circle back to the original post, here is (IMHO) a relatively succinct translation in Swift.  The key is that you can chain lazy properties.  Note that I used both a class function and a closure - either is fine.

```
import Swift

println("begin")

class ClassWithLazyProperties {

    lazy var entries:[String] = ClassWithLazyProperties.loadStuff()
    lazy var entriesByNumber:Dictionary<Int, String> = {

        var d = Dictionary<Int, String>()
        for i in 0..<self.entries.count {
            d[i] = self.entries[i]
        }
        return d
    }()

    private class func loadStuff() -> [String] {
        return ["Acai", "Apples", "Apricots", "Avocado", "Ackee", "Bananas", "Bilberries"]
    }

}

let c = ClassWithLazyProperties()
c.entriesByNumber
    // 0: "Acai", 1: "Apples", 2: "Apricots", 3: "Avocado", 4: "Ackee", 5: "Bananas", 6: "Bilberries"]


println("end")
```

Answer (score 12):

What about this:

```
class Container {

    lazy var entries: [String] = self.newEntries()

    func newEntries() -> [String] {

        // calculate and return entries

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. The opening { is missing after class name, and the return value in the function.

Comment: @Evgeny Fixed missing "{". Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could use an optional as the instance variable. Then create a function that returns the optional if it exists, and a new object if it does not to simulate lazy loading.

```
class Lazy {
    var lazyVariable:String?

    func lazilyGetEntries() -> String {
        if let possibleVariable = self.lazyVariable { // optional already exists
            return possibleVariable
        }
        else {                                        // optional does not exist, create it
            self.lazyVariable = String()
            return self.lazyVariable!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The way lazy works is that the initializer (or init method) runs only when the variable or property is first accessed. I see one main reason why it won't work (at least straight away) in your code, and that is because you packed two lazy instantiation code into one method (`loadEntriesIfNeeded`).

To use lazy instantiation, you might need to extend NSMutableArray and NSDictionary and override or create a custom initializer for your lazy instantiation. Then, distribute the code inside `loadEntriesIfNeeded` into their respective initializers.

In entries initializer:

```
NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.entriesDict count]];
[self.entriesDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *number, NSDictionary *entryDict, BOOL *stop) {
            Entry *entry = [[Entry alloc] initWithDictionary:entryDict container:self];
            [entries addObject:entry];}];
_entries = [entries copy];
```

Then in entriesByNumber initializer:

```
NSMutableDictionary *entriesByNumber = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[self.entriesDict count]];
// Then do fast enumeration accessing self.entries to assign values to entriesByNumber.
// If self.entries is null, the lazy instantiation should kick in, calling the above code
// and populating the entries variable.
_entriesByNumber = [entriesByNumber copy];
```

Then, you can create your lazy variables by calling on the custom initializers.

```
@lazy var entries: CustomArray = custominitforarray()
@lazy var entriesByNumber: CustomDictionary = custominitfordictionary()
```

PS: How come you don't have a property for entriesByNumber? I'm guessing it's private? Please test this out and reply about the result as I'm too lazy to do it myself.

Comment: it became just lazy, without "@" in beta4

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lazy Stored Properties in Swift to implement the Lazy Instantiation pattern. This is done by adding the `@lazy` attribute before the declaration of the stored property.

There are two things to keep in mind:

- Lazy properties must be initialized when declared
- Lazy properties can only be used on members of a struct or a class (hence why we need to use a DataManager)

---

Here's some code you can throw into a Playground to see how the `@lazy` attribute works

```
// initialize your lazily instantiated data
func initLazyData() -> String[] {
    return ["lazy data"]
}

// a class to manage the lazy data (along with any other data you want)
class DataManager {
    @lazy var lazyData = initLazyData()

    var otherData = "Other data"
}

// when we create this object, the "lazy data" array is not initialized
let manager = DataManager()

// even if we access another property, the "lazy data" array stays nil
manager.otherData += ", more data"
manager

// as soon as we access the "lazy data" array, it gets created
manager.lazyData
manager
```

---

For more information, you can check out the [Lazy Stored Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14) section on the Properties page of the Swift Programming Language Guide. Note that that link is to pre-release documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the @lazy attribute before its declaration.”

```
@lazy var lazyVariable:String? = ""
```

Please bear in mind, lazy property must have an initialiser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `@lazy` attribute in Swift. I found a small post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023664/lazy-attribute-in-swift-eqvivalent-to-lazy-init-getter-in-objective-c) and I recommend watching the three Swift video from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) (Introduction to Swift, Intermediate Swift, Advanced Swift). These videos show a lot of stuff and the advanced one really is advanced...

Comment: I've already watched all videos. Unfortunately, @lazy doesn't work here. Check out my code.

Comment: @Florian Unfortunately my developer program isn't activated yet so I can't run the code :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this in PageBaseApplication

```
var modelController: ModelController {
    // Return the model controller object, creating it if necessary.
    // In more complex implementations, the model controller may be passed to the view controller.
    if !_modelController {
        _modelController = ModelController()
    }
    return _modelController!
}

var _modelController: ModelController? = nil
```

similar to what @Brian Tracy mentioned but ussing variables instead of a func

Answer (score 0):

Since the `entries` property is just an array of the values in `entriesByNumber` you can do all the loading just in `entriesByNumber` and just have `entries` depend on `entriesByNumber`

```
lazy var entriesByNumber: [String : Entry] = {
        var ret: [String : Entry] = [:] 
        for (number, entryDict) in entriesDict
        {
            ret[number] = Entry(dictionary: entryDict, container: self)
        }
        return ret
    }

var entries: [Entry] 
{
    get { return self.entriesByNumber.values }
}
```