# Implementing a lazy property and setting it to nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-initialization

I would like to implement a lazy property so that it will not have a value until it is accessed for the first time. But then later I want to set it to `nil` to free up memory resources. Then when the app tries to access it again, it will be recreated, therefore it shouldn't ever be `nil` when it's about to be accessed.

I looked through the Swift Programming book and read up on lazy properties, but the information there is sparse, there was no example of this use case.

I saw [this answer by Rudolf Adamkovic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107938/lazy-property-initialization-in-swift) and implemented that format, but the project won't compile in Xcode 6.2 beta 3: `Use of undeclared type 'String'`

```
let model = MyModelClass()
lazy var recentlyAdded: [​String] = self.recents() //error here

func recents() -> [String] {
    return self.model.recentlyAdded()
}
```

I also tried this format, but it too fails to compile with the same compile-time error.

```
lazy var recentlyAdded: [​String] = self.model.recentlyAdded()
```

What is the proper way to implement this type of lazy property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. You cannot use the `lazy` property in Swift to perform lazy instantiation like you would in Objective-C, at least not with Swift 1-3. If you attempt to, it won't be instantiated until it's accessed for the first time, but if you set it to `nil` later on, when you go to access it again it will still be `nil`. It will only be lazily instantiated a single time, which is not what I wanted.

To implement 'true' lazy instantiation you'll need a computed property as well as a regular property, both `var`s. I'll term the regular property the "backing" property. Essentially, you check in the computed property if the backing property is `nil` and create it if it is, then return that backing property. This is a computed property so it doesn't store a value in memory, while the backing property does. When you wish to get its value, access the computed property. When you wish to set its value to `nil`, set the backing property.

Apple uses this technique in their Core Data templates. They use the same property name for both, but place an underscore before the backing property, which mimics an iVar from Objective-C.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    get {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }
        _fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: ...)
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
    set {
        _fetchedResultsController = newValue
    }
}
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

To use it:

```
_fetchResultsController = nil
self.fetchResultsController.performFetch()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
struct S {
    var _actualVar: String? = nil
    var lazyVar: String? {
        mutating get {
            if _actualVar == nil {
                _actualVar = someCalc()
            }
            return _actualVar
        }
        set(newVar) {
            _actualVar = newVar
        }
    }
}
var s = S()
s.lazyVar  // someCalc will be called
s.lazyVar  // but not here
s.lazyVar = nil
s.lazyVar  // but it'll be called again here
```

Note, as with a lazy property, this does require that to use the `get` version of `lazyVar`, your `s` variable still has to be declared with `var` which can be a bit surprising.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out the issue. But I solved it.

When I copied your code and pasted, I got the same error:

```
Use of undeclared type 'String'
```

I deleted that and re-typed it (Without auto-completion) and it worked for me.

Looks like a bug in XCode.

Comment: Interesting! Both of them worked for you? Did you run the app or just build it? I can't get either to work but I'll try it again.

Comment: @Joey: When I copy pasted, it is not working. When I re-typed the String class name it worked for me. Successfully build and run

Comment: @Joey: I implemented it like: `class MyModelClass
{
    func recentlyAdded() -> [String]{
        return ["7"];
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    let model = MyModelClass()
    lazy var recentlyAdded: [String] = self.recents() //error here
    
    func recents() -> [String] {
        return self.model.recentlyAdded()
    }}`

Comment: Ok, it's not complaining for me now on that line after retyping it, however when I try to set it to `nil` it says [String] doesn't conform to nil literal convertible. I changed it to `[String]?` and it runs but after setting it to `nil` the next time you access it it does not lazily instantiate again, it's `nil`.

Comment: @Joey: It only works for the first time. If you need to initialize it again, write your own custom property

Comment: I thought `lazy` properties could bet set to `nil` and lazily instantiated when accessed as many times as you wanted, just like in Obj-C. :/ Well that is the question, how to implement that behavior. What would this custom property look like?

Comment: @Joey: I mean you can write your own getter and setter for this. In that case you don't need any lazy property. When you access a getter the value will be returned (something like a method returns value). Please check that option

Comment: That would be a computed property, whose value is not stored in memory but rather created every time it is accessed, which is undesirable in this case.

Comment: @Joey: if you need you can store that value. There is an option for that too.

Comment: That must be what I'm looking for then, can you explain that approach?

Comment: That’s essentially what I describe in my answer - a computed get and set property backed by an actual variable.

Answer (score -1):

I'd just use the optional notation - ie a question mark to indicate it can be nil. For example

```
var myVar:String?
```